# Can I more simply express this summation?

Tags: summation

I've been trying to make the below equation more simple such like binomial theorem: 
$\sum^{n}_{i=0} \binom ni a^ib^{n-i}=(a+b)^n$.

The equation I want to make more simple is :  $\sum^{n-1}_{i=0} \binom ni i! x^{-i}$.

Does anybody have any idea to simplify it?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: The expression simplifies if you're allowed access to the incomplete gamma function, but that's basically just rephrasing the sum.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The incomplete gamma function is very useful for me!